# Eclipse C/C++ Ignore Breakpoints

Tags: c++, c, eclipse

i installed eclipse and wantet to debug, but it ignores all Breakpoints.

I added the Mingw bin path it doesnt helped

Can enyone help me ?

Comment: and i didnt push the skip all breakpoints button, i already checked

Comment: i am using Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers

Version: Neon.2 Release (4.6.2)
Build id: 20161208-0600

Comment: Does it even stop if a breakpoint is placed in `main`? No code in the question means there is no knowing if it's a problem with your code or eclipse. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: no it starts just at the beginning of the code i tryed a very simple code with just some variables and a cout but it doesnt worked

Comment: Are you running a build with debug symbols? Is your debugger configured properly?

Comment: i dont know what you mean with debug symbols
im just clicking on debug
What does properly mean ? I addes the min gw bin path

Comment: i am using GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1